# Error:The TCP/IP connection to the host has failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, database-connection, tcp

I am using

- Windows 7
- Netbeans IDE 7.1.2
- SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005
- JDK1.6

I am getting the below error while connecting to the database:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

My connection string is:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=dbcm;" +  
    "user=sa;password=sa");
```

I've checked below things:

1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, Protocols for SQLEXPRESS : TCP/IP Enabled
   In fact I made enable remaining 3 too.
2. SQL Server(SQLExpress) and SQL Browser Service both are running.

Comment: Did you check windows' firewall settings ?

Comment: Try to omit the port number. Make sure SQLServerBrowser Service is running. Try using `localhost` instead of IP address. Check your firewall settings.

Comment: You must add your instance name like `;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS` if you are using one.

Comment: @Pierre Henry : Yes,I checked firewall settings.

Comment: @MicSim : SQLBrowser Service is running. Typed localhost instead of IP address also added instanceName. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: One last shot: Is your instance configured for TCP/IP authentication, or maybe Windows authentication only?

Comment: Is the sqlserver running at all? Check `netstat` in a cmd-window. Is there a line `TCP 127.0.0.1:1433 ...`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I followed the steps below to successfully connect to an SQLExpress instance using JDBC:

1. Configure TCP/IP communication with SQL Express

   1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
   2. Go to SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
   3. Set the status of TCP/IP protocol to "Enabled" (if it is already not).
   4. Open Properties window for TCP/IP, go to IP Addresses section.
   5. Go to the bottom of this property page and set the TCP Port under `IPAll` to 1433.
2. Connect to the SQLExpress instance using `Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server`

   1. JDBC URL: `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=<your DB>;user=<your User>;password=<your Passwd>`